# How to access views in classes using viewbinding?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewbinding, kotlin-extension

I have a XML file and I want to use a text view from inside that, to the best of my knowledge, view binding can be used to access views from id using:

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
binding.<textview_id_name>.text = "Some Text"
```

But I wish to access a view in another class which does not extend AppCompatActivity class.

My MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object CompanionObject{
        lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this);
    }
}
```

Class from which I want to access textview named 'titleView', I want to have something like this.

```
titleView.text = "Some Message"
```

Comment: `But I wish to access a view in another class which does not extend AppCompatActivity class.` this is most likely a bad idea, regardless of using viewbinding, what's the point of doing that ?

Comment: Do not put a binding reference in a companion object! This will leak your views.